# Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.5 Error?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-task

I'm writing an application and trying to execute **task** using Terminal command `gradle task1` created in app/build.gradle file. But it giving following error.

> Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.5. If using the
>   gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
>   /home/user/workplace/Project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-2.10-all.zip

I checked with **gradle-wrapper.properties** and there **distributionUrl** attribute pointing same 2.10 version. distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

what is wrong here, any suggestion !!

Comment: Have to tried to rebuild your project and clean again ?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh..that is because I was trying to build task using Gradle install on local machine. Instead I tried with project directory

> ./gradlew task1

and this worked fine.